# How to send a Telegram message for every row with data in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram

I'm actually using this working code and setting a trigger to repeat the task every 4 hours, but I would like to short the code checking every row, let's say look for non empty rows in the range 'A1:A20'.
[image]

What can be the short path to run the script without the use of this code?

```
function sendTelegramNotification() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TELEGRAM");

if (sheet.getRange("A1").isBlank()) return;
var api = sheet.getRange("A1").getValues();
var group = sheet.getRange("B1").getValues();
var message = sheet.getRange("C1").getValues();

  var url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + api
    + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + group
    + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(message)
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

if (sheet.getRange("A2").isBlank()) return;
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(80 * 100);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
var api = sheet.getRange("A2").getValues();
var group = sheet.getRange("B2").getValues();
var message = sheet.getRange("C2").getValues();

  var url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + api
    + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + group
    + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(message)
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

if (sheet.getRange("A3").isBlank()) return;

//etc., etc.
}
```

Comment: You should use FOR loop and iterate through the range. You can address cells using row and column number getRange(1,1) makes A1,.

Comment: I agree with the first comment, also provided a sample sheet with sample data created under a dummy account for testing purposes

Comment: @DiegoSanchez I attached an screenshot, just to not share the bot id and the chat id, I already post my answer, but I would like to not search in all the sheet rows, only in a range 'A1:A20', for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) instead of `getDataRange()` for `var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` and specify the rows and columns. Here is an example implementation

```
function sendWeater() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var data = sheet.getRange(1,1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

 //Wait some seconds to send every message
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(80 * 100);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  //Loop for all the rows in the sheet 'TELEGRAM', i = 1 because I've a header row
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var api = row[0];
    var group = row[1];
    var message = row[2];

  var url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + api
    + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + group
    + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(message)
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  } 
}
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to test this due to limited access to Telegram Bot, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve it by using this code:

```
function sendWeater() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TELEGRAM");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Wait some seconds to send every message
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(80 * 100);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  //Loop for all the rows in the sheet 'TELEGRAM', i = 1 because I've a header row
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var api = row[0];
    var group = row[1];
    var message = row[2];

  var url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + api
    + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + group
    + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(message)
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  }
}
```